# React-Native MobX-State-Tree store unavailable on registerComponent

Tags: react-native, mobx, inject, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

Given the following setup:

```
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
import Application from "./src/components/Application";
import ApplicationStore from "./src/stores/ApplicationStore";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";

let app = ApplicationStore.create();

AppRegistry.registerComponent(name, () => (
  <Provider app={app}>
    <Application />
  </Provider>
));
```

ApplicationStore is undefined, and thus cannot be created...

`Cannot read property 'create' of undefined`

`Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)`

Is there a better way to setup the ApplicationStore, and make it available for components via inject?

```
const Application = inject("app")(
  observer(
    class Application extends Component {
    ...
```

This is how I've done in in react apps () albeit via `ReactDOM.render()`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so due diligence for the win!

```
import React from "react";
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
import Application from "./src/components/Application";
import { ApplicationStore } from "./src/stores/ApplicationStore";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";

const app = ApplicationStore.create();
const ApplicationProvider = () => {
  return (
    <Provider app={app}>
      <Application />
    </Provider>
  );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => ApplicationProvider);
```

and then inside your component:

```
const Application = inject("app")(
  observer(
    class Application extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Application</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Now the store is available for all components and instantiated on the start of the app...